# How can I make a turtle look at another turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am supposed to write a program that makes a turtle follow another one. All I need is a function that turns the following turtle towards the one running away.

Comment: What did you try, why does that not work, where are you stuck?

Comment: honestly not a lot. I was wondering if there is an already defined function that would turn a turtle towards another object.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090804-00/?p=17233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a function but a pair of functions:

```
chase_turtle.setheading(chase_turtle.towards(flee_turtle))
```

`.towards()` gets the angle to the other turtle and `.setheading()` aligns your turtle to it.

Make sure to keep the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html) at the ready when you program with turtles.